# PHP script not displaying all images from directory

Tags: php, html, image

I'm trying to build a webpage that displays images from a folder using PHP. But for some reason it stopped displaying all images within the image folder and only a partial amount. I have pagination within the function, but not all images are being displayed. I checked the directory to ensure the files were in there and they are.

When counting the files I get a total of 76 according to php. The directory has 74 images. But my page is only displaying 60 images. Please help me fix this!

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<?php
            function show_pagination($current_page, $last_page){
                echo '<br><div>';
                if( $current_page > 1 ){
                    echo ' <button class="button" type="button"><a href="?page='.($current_page-1).'">&lt;&lt;Previous</a></button> ';
                }

                    for($i = 1; $i <= $last_page; $i++){
                            echo ' <button class="button" type="button"><a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></button> ';
                    }

                if( $current_page < $last_page ){
                    echo ' <button class="button" type="button"><a href="?page='.($current_page+1).'">Next&gt;&gt</a></button> ';
                }
                echo '</div><br>';
                    echo '<div><p>Page '.$current_page.' out of '.$last_page.'</p></div><br>';
            }


            $folder = 'images/';
            $filetype = '*.*';
            $files = glob($folder.$filetype);
            $total = count($files);
            $per_page = 20;
            $last_page = (int)($total / $per_page);
            if(isset($_GET["page"])  && ($_GET["page"] <= $last_page) && ($_GET["page"] > 0) ){
                $page = $_GET["page"];
                $offset = ($per_page * ($page - 1)) + 1;
            }else{
                //echo "Page out of range showing results for page one";
                $page=1;
                $offset=0;
            }
            $max = $offset + $per_page;
            if($max>$total){
                $max = $total;
            }
            echo "Total number of files is $total";

            show_pagination($page, $last_page);
            for($i = $offset; $i< $max; $i++){
                $file = $files[$i];
                $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
                $filename = $path_parts['filename'];
                        echo "<a href='$file'><img src='$file' alt='$filename' style='height: 30%; width: 30%; border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;border-color: #000000; margin: 5px'></a>";
            }
            show_pagination($page, $last_page);

        ?>
```

This was working for me at some point and now it doesn't so I'm wondering if there's something inherently wrong with my PHP code. I am new to php.

Comment: Have you check the Image src?

Comment: Try using `ceil()` instead of `int` in `$last_page = (int)($total / $per_page);`

Comment: Thank you @Sinto that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `int` used in your code line:

```
$last_page = (int)($total / $per_page);
```

Instead of that use `ceil()` as:

```
$last_page = ceil($total / $per_page);
```

Reason is that total image 74/20 gives 3.7, if we use `int` result will be 3. But its more than that. If we use `ceil()`, even 3.1 will be converted as 4. So you will not miss any image.

Comment: Here I added that as an answer for you.